# XML insert via XSLT (xalan) produces xmlns entries in output XML

Tags: xml, maven, xslt, xalan

At the moment I'm trying to figure out how to insert a new server credential to a maven settings.xml using XSL (xalan 2.7.1). My problem is, that the output XML always has an empty `xmlns=""` element in his tag which Maven doesn't like!

Thats the base XML:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
...
    <!-- Server Credentials -->
    <servers>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

My XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:mvn="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="mvn xsl xslt">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" xslt:indent-amount="4" />
<xsl:param name="server.id" />
<xsl:param name="server.username" />
<xsl:param name="server.password" />

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mvn:servers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <server>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.id" />
            </id>
            <username>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.username" />
            </username>
            <password>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.password" />
            </password>
        </server>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

At the end of the transformation, it Looks like this:

```
    <!-- Server Credentials -->
    <servers>
    <server xmlns="">
            <id>nexus-nbg</id>
            <username>testuser</username>
            <password>{PMjrq7GDvwgH4xBziBIjb71GZSlgovs6D85zXogvP9I=}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
```

So it inserts an empty `xmlns`-Tag which Maven doesn't like and prints some WARNINGS. Also the First `server`-Tag has also the wrong indention?! So i'm already mapping the namespaces, so that the matcher works and i also included the `exlude-result-prefixes` What else i have to do?!

Would be happy if anyone here hase an idea!

Best wishes,

Daniel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
<xsl:template match="mvn:servers">
    <xsl:copy>
```

you are copying the `servers` element from the source document - including its original namespace. But the added child `server` element is in no-namespace - and the XSLT processor adds an empty `xmlns=""` namespace declaration to mark it so.

If you want the added child element to be in the same namespace as its `servers` parent, you must place it there explicitly:

```
<xsl:template match="mvn:servers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <server xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0">
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.id" />
            </id>
            <username>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.username" />
            </username>
            <password>
                <xsl:value-of select="$server.password" />
            </password>
        </server>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You could achieve the same thing by moving the default `xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"` namespace declaration to the `stylesheet` element. Then any literal result element in your stylesheet will be automatically placed in the default namespace, unless you override this by another namespace declaration.